# Extract specific fasta sequences from a big fasta file

Tags: python, biopython

I want to extract specific fasta sequences from a big fasta file using the following script, but the output is empty.

The `transcripts.txt` file contains the list transcripts IDs that I want to export (both the IDs and the sequences) from `assembly.fasta` to `selected_transcripts.fasta`. 
For example:

1. transcripts.txt:

   ```
   Transcript_00004|5601
   Transcript_00005|5352
   ```
2. assembly.fasta:

   ```
   >Transcript_00004|5601
   GATCTGGCGCTGAGCTGGGTGCTGATCGACCCGGCGTCCGGCCGCTCCGTGAACGCCTCGAGTCGGCGCCCGGTGTGCGTTGACCGGAGATCGCGATCTGGGGAGACCGTCGTGCGGTT
   >Transcript_00004|5360
   CGATCTGGCGCTGAGCTGGGTGCTGATCGACCCGGCGTCCGGCCGCTCCGTGAACGCCTCGAGTCGGCGCCCGGTGTGCGTTGACCGGAGATCGCGATCTGGGGAGACCGTCGTGCGGTT
   ```

The IDs are preceded by the `>` symbol: `>Transcripts_00004|5601`.

I have to read the `assembly.fasta` file, if the transcript ID in `assembly.fasta` is the same of that write in `transcripts.txt`, I have to write this transcript ID and its sequence in `selected_transcripts.fasta`. So, in the example above, I have to write only the first transcript.

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

```
from Bio import SeqIO

my_list = [line.split(',') for line in open("/home/universita/transcripts.txt")]

fin = open('/home/universita/assembly.fasta', 'r')
fout = open('/home/universita/selected_transcripts.fasta', 'w')

for record in SeqIO.parse(fin,'fasta'):
    for item in my_list:
        if item == record.id:
            fout.write(">" + record.id + "\n")
            fout.write(record.seq + "\n")

fin.close()
fout.close()
```

Comment: see https://www.biostars.org/p/68718/

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and include some of `transcripts.txt` as well as a portion of `assembly.fasta` so we have some data to work with?

Comment: You split your transcripts line after each colon but it is space separated. Is that on purpose?

Comment: Your example FASTA file has no > in the header line.

Comment: Sorry, in the trascripts.txt, each ID is a line of the file. So the first transcript in the example is in the 1st lane, the second transcript is in the 2nd lane and so on.

Comment: And in the assembly.fasta, each ID is preceded by >.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your examples there a couple of small problems which may explain why you don't get anything. Your `transcripts.txt` has multiple entries in one line, therefore `my_list` will have all the items of the first_line in `my_line[0]`, in your loop you iterate through `my_list` by lines, so your first item will be

`['Transcript_00004|5601', 'Transcript_00005|5352']`

Also if `assembly.fasta` has no `>` in the header line you won't get back any records with IDs and sequences. The following code should take care of those problems, assuming you added `>` to the headers and the `split` function is now using space and not colon.

```
from Bio import SeqIO

my_list = []
with open("transcripts.txt") as transcripts:
    for line in transcripts:
        my_list.extend(line.split(' '))

fin = open('assembly.fasta', 'r')
fout = open('selected_transcripts.fasta', 'w')

for record in SeqIO.parse(fin,'fasta'):
    for item in my_list:
        if item.strip() == record.id:
            fout.write(">" + record.id + "\n")
            fout.write(record.seq + "\n")


fin.close()
fout.close()
```

Reading of transcript was changed so that all IDs are appended to `my_list` separately. Also each item is stripped of white space in order to avoid having line breaks in the string when it is compared to the `record.id`.